# I want to generate 24 hour data(by filtering the date column to 24 hours) in KUSTO by adding custom start time and endtime values

Tags: azure, kql, kusto-explorer, adx

[image: input and expected output]
I have date and status values in a table, i want to select the date range for a period of 24h, I want to get all the status values including starting and ending date values. But those values were not present in the table. It has to get it from previous record.

I have attached the sample data in the screenshot for better understanding.

I have tried by creating a column with prev() staus value and by doing this i am not able to get the last record and its status value.

Can you help how can i get both starting and ending custom date values.

Also for selected time period if there is no data found, it should display the previous record. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used some dummy data to create a table. The UDF created expects starttime and endtime parameters to achieve the desired result asked in question.

**Code/Query**

```
let  myFunc = (CustomStartDate : datetime ,CustomEndDate : datetime )
{
//Created temporary table named "tbl"    
let  tbl = datatable(Time: datetime , Status: string )
[
datetime(2023-03-16 07:14:58.4785756), "Running",
datetime(2023-03-16 11:15:49.7803968), "Stopped",
datetime(2023-03-16 13:46:31.8371005), "Idle",
datetime(2023-03-16 21:00:00.0000000),"Stopped",
datetime(2023-03-16 23:00:00.0000000),"Running",
datetime(2023-03-17 05:16:51.9252773), "Stopped",
datetime(2023-03-17 13:16:51.9252773), "Running"
];
//selecting records which falls between start date and end date and creating new temporary table named "tbl1"
let  tbl1 = tbl | where  Time  between ( CustomStartDate .. CustomEndDate);
//creating 2 variables to store minimum and maximum time values within the custom time provided to get the previous and current status
let  minDate = tbl1 | summarize  min(Time);
let  maxDate = tbl1 | summarize  max(Time);
let  PreStatus = tbl | where  Time < toscalar(minDate)| order  by  Time  desc | project  Status | take 1;
let  CustomEndStatus = tbl1 | where  Time == toscalar(maxDate) |project  Status ;
//Union custom dates and status with tbl1 and sorted the table on basis of Time ascending order.
tbl1
| union (print  Time = CustomStartDate, Status = toscalar(PreStatus))
| union (print  Time = CustomEndDate, Status = toscalar(CustomEndStatus ))
| order  by  Time  asc
};
myFunc(datetime(2023-03-16 20:00:00.0000000),datetime(2023-03-17 12:00:00.0000000))
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: for the first record it should display Idle, as this time range is between datetime(2023-03-16 13:46:31.8371005) and datetime(2023-03-16 21:00:00.0000000). It should take previous record status which is Idle

Comment: @SwathiMiney I have updated answer to get previous status. Please check.

Comment: Thank you :-). my issue is resolved now.